# Storage disk delete image from db

Tags: laravel

I have this error when i trying to delete an image from db:
Undefined variable: removeslider

```
public function delete($id){
     $getslider = DB::table('slider')->where('id',$id)->get();
     foreach($getslider as $getslider) {
     $removeslider = $getslider->bgimage;
     }
        Storage::disk('uploadssliders')->delete($removeslider);
        return redirect('admin/inicio');
   }
```

Comment: The `$removeslider` variable is not set because  your `foreach` loop is not iterating this probably has to do with both arguments being the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```php
public function delete($id)
{
    $getslider = DB::table('slider')->where('id',$id)->first();
    if($getslider){
         Storage::disk('uploadssliders')->delete($getslider->bgimage);
         return redirect('admin/inicio');
    } else {
         //id has no match in the database
         echo "the id ". $id . " does not exist";
    }  
}
```

I changed your `get()` to `first()` to only get one result as this seems what you are trying to do then the `foreach` is not needed.

Comment: i tryied too but have this error Trying to get property 'bgimage' of non-object

Comment: does the `$id` you give the query match the database ? is there a `bgimage` column in the table `slider` ? it seems the query you are making does not give any results. i will edit my answer to account for this.

Comment: Did my solution work for you or did you use something else ?